# join two sql table as column

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have two tables as below:

firsttable

| id | cat_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | name_01 |
| 2 | 2 | name_02 |
| 3 | 1 | name_03 |
| 4 | 3 | name_04 |
| 5 | 3 | name_04 |

secondtable

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat_01 |
| 2 | cat_02 |
| 3 | cat_03 |

my question is how can i create below table result?

| id(secondtable) | name(secondtable) | count(firsttable) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat_01 | 1 |
| 2 | cat_02 | 2 |
| 3 | cat_03 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t2.id,t2.name,
(select count(*) from firsttable t1 where t1.cat_id=t2.id )as count
from secendtable t2;
```

Comment: I don't think this query is getting proper output because if i have 10 category more in the second table so this query result will show 10 category with zero count .

Answer (score 1):

Just using standard aggregation

```
select
  s.id,
  s.name,
  count(*)
from firsttable f
  join secondtable s
    on f.cat_id = s.id
group by s.id, s.name order by s.id
```

Comment: If some categories are missing in the `firsttable` then use RIGHT JOIN to get all categories.

Comment: @Serg I don't think any issue in this query If some categories are missing in the FIRST_TABLE ?

Answer (score 0):

It's very Simple like that

```
SELECT s.id,s.name, (SELECT count(*) 
FROM `firsttable` AS f 
WHERE f.cat_id = s.id ) as count 
FROM `secondtable` AS s
```

Comment: Is there anything different in your query than the query in the accepted answer which was posted 20 mins earlier?

Comment: I have checked the question and I was trying to generate a SQL query, after that we answered and the page was refreshed then we got the answer already accepted. without page refresh manually we can't get the answer accepted or not!

Comment: @forpas, yes. This query is worse indented than the previous one